# Perl's HTML::Element - dumping just the descendants as HTML

Tags: perl, xpath, html-parsing, html-tree

I'm having trouble trying to output the contents of a matched node that I'm parsing:

```
<div class="description">some text <br/>more text<br/></div>
```

I'm using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` to find the node (there's only one div with this class):

```
my $description = $tree->findnodes('//div[@class="description"]')->[0];
```

It finds the node (returned as a `HTML::Element` I believe) but `$description->as_HTML` includes the element itself too - I just want everything contained inside the element as HTML:

```
some text <br/>more text<br/>
```

I can obviously regex strip it out, but that feels messy and I'm sure I'm just missing a function somewhere to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
my $description = $tree->findnodes('//div[@class="description"]/text()')->[0];
```

This is a Xpath trick.

Comment: That returns an object of type HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath::TextNode which doesn't have the 'as_HMTL' method (and I can't seem to find any docs as to what it does provide)

Answer (score 0):

Use `./node()` to fetch all subnodes including text and elements.

```
my $description = $tree->findnodes('//div[@class="description"]/node()');
```

Comment: It has the same issue as using text(), the returned object is HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath::TextNode and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: This call will return *multiple* nodes (all nodes contained), so it should be a container containing all the elements. It will return some list or a `Tree::XPathEngine::NodeSet` object in scalar mode (what you're forcing it). You'll probably have to iterate over the result in some way. Oh and have a look at the `->[0]` in the end, I guess it's probably wrong here (because you want all nodes, not only the first). I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Yeah looking at the list returned its a mixture of `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath::TextNode` and `HTML::Element`, which are lists themselves.  It'd be extremely fiddly and annoying just to accomplish what I want, so at this rate I may as well just get rid of the parent tag with regex!

Comment: If you'll apply regex, you should be happy with a string anyway? You know [`findnodes_as_string`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath-0.14/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm#findnodes_as_string_($path))?